# Como hacer varios console.log( ) y que el resultado aparezca en una misma línea

Tags: javascript

Ejemplo quiero imprimir esto:

```
1 1,2,3,4,5,6
2 1,2,3,4,5,6
3 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Código:

```
let numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let numeros2= "";

for (i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
    for (j=0; j<numeros.length; j++){
        numeros2 = Array in numeros;
    };
    console.log(numeros[i] + " " + numeros2);
};    // esto es lo que tengo
```

quiero imprimir en consola lo de arriba

Comment: ¿Quieres que tu resultado sea `1 1,2,3,4,5,6 2 1,2,3,4,5,6 3 1,2,3,4,5,6 4 1,2,3,4,5,6 5 1,2,3,4,5,6 6 1,2,3,4,5,6`?

Comment: Con el método .join() podes pasar el array a cadena de texto.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el resultado sea :`1 1,2,3,4,5,6 2 1,2,3,4,5,6 3 1,2,3,4,5,6 4 1,2,3,4,5,6 5 1,2,3,4,5,6 6 1,2,3,4,5,6`

```
  let numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  let numeros2 = "";
  for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    numeros2 += i < numeros.length - 1 ? numeros[i] + " " + numeros + " " : numeros[i] + " " + numeros;
  };
  console.log(numeros2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un código que podría aplicar:

```
let numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
  let line = numeros[i] + ",";

  for (let j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
    line += numeros[j] + ",";
  }

  console.log(line.slice(0, -1));
}
```

Con eso podrá ver en consola:

```
1,1,2,3,4,5,6
2,1,2,3,4,5,6
3,1,2,3,4,5,6
4,1,2,3,4,5,6
5,1,2,3,4,5,6
6,1,2,3,4,5,6
```